# Datasnap service doesn't release memory after the session ends

Tags: delphi, datasnap

I'm working with the Rest service of Datasnap in Delphi 10.3, I have noticed that when calling the service methods, the memory is only allocated and when ending the session with the client it is not released.

The DSServerClass1 lifecycle is configured for "invocation", but even putting it for "session", does not affect the behavior. According to the documentation, the memory should be deallocated after 20 minutes, but it does not happen.

I'm using TFDJSONDataSetsWriter to return the Dataset of the query, which according to the documentation should release TFDQuery, but apparently it doesn't.

Below is a simplification of the method:

```
var
     FdConnection: TFDConnection;
     Query: TFDQuery;
begin
 try
          FdConnection: = TFDConnection.Create (nil);
          FdConnection.DriverName: = 'SQLITE';
          FDConnection.Params.Values ​​['Database']: = 'database.db';
          FDConnection.Params.Values ​​['OpenMode']: = 'Readwrite';
          FDConnection.Params.Values ​​['LockingMode']: = 'Normal';

          Query: = TFDQuery.Create (nil);
          Query.Connection: = FDConnection;

          Query.sql.Clear;
          Query.sql.Add ('select * from table');
          Query.open;
             
         Result: = TFDjsonDataSets.create;
         TFDJSONDataSetsWriter.ListAdd (Result, Query);
    
      finally
         //FdConnection.free;
         //Query.free;
      end;
```

Any suggestions on how to release the components or any other approach?

Comment: How are you checking that the memory isn't released?

Comment: @martyna I am following the service through the process manager.

Comment: If you mean Task Manager, that doesn't tell you whether Delphi objects' memory gets deallocated.  See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Configuring_the_Memory_Manager for how to do this.

Comment: Off-topic, but still very important: you MUST put `FdConnection := TFDConnection.Create (nil);` BEFORE the `try`, and you need a separate (nested) `try..finally` for the `TFDQuery`.